# Short Story Time Travel from the Early 2000s, Maybe Earlier?

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, time-travel

I don't remember much about the story in general, but here's the details I can recall.

It's a short story, intended for a 5th or 6th grade reading level, and I found it in the early 2000s in a collection of stories, the rest being lost to memory. In the story, somehow a kid finds out his neighbor has a time machine in his garage, or his neighbor might have told him about it. Either way, his neighbor proves his time machine by procuring a fully blooming rose in the middle of December.

I can't remember the end. It might have been published before 2000, maybe after.

Comment: Did it involve a radio?

Comment: @amflare It might have? What are you thinking?

Comment: I recall some book from early 2000s about a kid who had a neighbor who had a radio in his garage that was set a day in the future. It didn't have a rose as proof though, so its might not be the same book.

Comment: @amflare No, that doesn't sound like it. But that does sound interesting. What book is it?

Comment: I don't recall the title and a cursory search isn't yielding any results.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[LAFFF by Lensey Namioka](http://handouts.abs.edu.kw/elem/Assignments%20%20Handouts/Grade%2005/English/Journeys%20Unit%20Stories/G5%20-%20LAFFF.PDF) (PDF file)

Neighbors:

> Peter's family, like ours, had immigrated from China, but they had
>   settled here first. When we moved into a house just two doors down
>   from the Lu's, they gave us some good advice on how to get along in
>   America.

Garage:

> One evening, as I was coming home from a babysitting job, I cut across
>   the Lus' backyard. Passing their garage, I saw through a little window
>   that the light was on. My curiosity got the better of me, and I peeked
>   in.

Rose:

> He held a red rose in his hand. “What do you think of that?” I
>   blinked. “So you produced a flower. Maybe you had it under the stool.”
>   “Roses bloom in June, right?” he demanded. That was true. And this was
>   December. “I sent myself forward in time to June when the flowers were
>   blooming,” said Peter.

Comment: Yes, this is it, thank you so much!